# How to create correct notifications with django getstream?

Tags: django, django-models, getstream-io

I create notifications system with getstream.io in Django and works good but, in one situation I don't know how to correctly do this.

I have Django and this app: https://github.com/GetStream/stream-django

Normally I create notification as in tutorial in link above, and this work well.

```
class Follow(models.Model, Activity):

@property
def activity_notify(self):
    return [feed_manager.get_notification_feed(self.target_user.id)]
```

Now I need something difficult. I have 3 models.

```
class Goal(models.Model, Activity):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Tytuł')
  image = models.ImageField(blank=True, verbose_name='Tło')
  body = HTMLField(verbose_name='Treść')
  votes = GenericRelation(LikeDislike, related_query_name='goalvotes')
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Joined(models.Model, Activity):
  goal = models.ForeignKey(Goal, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='joined_goal')
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='joined_users')
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and

```
class Comment(models.Model, Activity):
   body = models.TextField()
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=CASCADE)
```

and my goal is to send notification about new comment in goal to all users who already joined to goal. I try something like this:

```
@property
def activity_notify(self):
   return [feed_manager.get_notification_feed(Joined.user.id)]
```

I know this is wrong, but I have no other idea how to do this. Maybe someone have solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your database schema does not have enough information to generate the right notification target group. You should add a reference between a `Comment` and a `Goal`

```
class Comment(models.Model, Activity):
   goal = models.ForeignKey(Goal, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   body = models.TextField()
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=CASCADE)
```

This way now you can create the list of users to notify like this

```
@property
def activity_notify(self):
   user_ids = self.goal.joined_goal.values_list('id', flat=True).order_by('id')
   return map(feed_manager.get_notification_feed, user_ids[:100])
```

Disclaimer: I did not tested this code, some tweaks might be necessary

Comment: Thanks for helping me. Now I see error: "Invalid user id <QuerySet [2, 3]>, please only use letters, numbers and _"

Comment: Django's QuerySets are lazily evaluated; in this case you need to iterate on it (see my update)

Comment: I change this, and now is that: "Invalid user id [2, 3], please only use letters, numbers and _".

Comment: @MaciejUrmański see last change

Comment: Hmm now I don't have any error. In getstream dashboard i don't see any notification about this activity. I see others like join to goal or follow user but nothing about this comment notification. In my portal too, I create template for this notification like others but this notification just don't work and I don't know why.

Comment: Getstream search for user id yes? I don't sure but in this example I see "**joined_goal**" related name is used. But it's only give me list of goals not users, I'm right?